# Unix/Linux - Replace words between parentheses

Tags: text-processing

I want to replace words between parentheses in unix/Linux- as an example below. I am trying to automate this so that it makes my work easy with just one code included.

I have the below string in my ksh script

```
   echo "Export file to below names (ABC, DEF, GHI)"
```

I would like to be as below

```
   echo "Export file to below names ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')"
```

Comment: With Vim: `:%s/(\zs.*\ze)/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\w\+', "'&'", 'g')/`

Comment: I have tried using sed command which is mentioned below by Ipor. But it didn't worked as it put quotations after each words.

sed -e "s/\($1\)/'\1'/g"

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "Export file to below names (ABC, DEF, GHI)" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\)/'\1'/g"
Export file to below names ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
```

Comment: Thanks Ipor. What if I have condition like this ------
WHERE Name in (NEW,OLD,CLOSED)
Can we use the same command to change it to ('NEW','OLD','CLOSED') ?

Comment: `sed -e "s/\([A-Z]*\)\([,)]\)/'\1'\2/g"` or `sed -e "s/\([A-Z][A-Z]\+\)/'\1'/g`

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, almost in a readable way:

```
echo "Export file to below names (ABC, DEF, GHI)" |  
  perl -lne '@a = /(.*\()(.*)(\).*)/; $a[1] =~ s/\w+/\x27$&\x27/g; print @a'
```

The first match splits the line in three parts and captures all: anything up to a left parenthesis (`(.*\()`), anything (`(.*)`), and a right parenthesis plus anything (`(\).*)`). We drop them into array `@a`, and run a substitution on the second element (counting from zero). The substitution
 `s/\w+/\x27$&\x27/g` matches strings of "word characters" (`\w+`) and replaces with the matching part (from `$&`) surrounded by single quotes. The quotes are escaped in hex to avoid an annoying quote-dance with the shell.

---

Of course with Perl you could do unreadable stuff too, like a sed-style substitution within another substitution:

```
echo "Export file to below names (ABC, DEF, GHI)" |
  perl -pe 's,\(.*\), $_ = $&; s/\w+/\x27$&\x27/g; $_ ,e; ' 
Export file to below names ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
```

Here, the final `e` makes the outer substitution interpret the replacement as a snippet of Perl code, which takes the matching part from `$&`, and edits it as above. I used `$_` as a temporary variable here since `$&` is read-only.
The replacement snipped could be moved to a function, which would perhaps make the line more readable.

Comment: Is there any way we can replace a string like below, just need to replace character strings only-                                                                                           

Where Name in (old, new, closed) and value in (1,2,3)  

to 

Where Name in ('old', 'new', 'closed') and value in (1,2,3)

Comment: @nehal, yeah, of course. Instead of the `\w` I used, you can give a list of characters in brackets to match any of them, like `[xyz]`, or even a range `[a-zA-Z]`. Look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes) for more, there's a bunch of examples. That's specifically for Perl regular expressions, `sed` and others differ annoyingly in various little places, so some study may be required when changing tools.